# Firestore Transaction: How to write function that can be the Initiator & non-Initiator of a Transaction?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have an `updateLog()` function that does the following:

**Just a Pseudo:**

```
const updateLog = (logData) => {
   return db.runTransaction( t => {
      return t.get(logRef)
         .then(log => {
            if (!log.exists) {
               // blah blah blah
            } else {
               // blah blah blah
            }
         }
   }
}
```

But I also have another function that **can be the initiator of the transaction** and the `updateLog()` function can only be a **part of the transaction**:

```
const createDoc = (docData) => {
   return db.runTransaction( t => {
      t.set(docRef, docData);
      // Here, the updateLog() can only be part of the transaction.
      return updateLog(docData, t???)
         .then(result => {
            if (!result) {
               // blah blah blah
            } else {
               // blah blah blah
            }
         }
   }
}
```

**QUESTION:** So in my `updateLog()`, can I accept the `transaction` as an optional parameter at the same time still retain its ability to be an **independent transaction initiator**? As such, how do I create an optional parameter for `updateLog()` that get the `runTransaction` to **OPTIONALLY** accept it as part of the transaction? The reason why I want to do this is because I want to avoid duplicating the logic in the `runTransaction` block or writing another "proxy" or "router" that manages the availability of the transaction. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

```
const updateLog = (logData, transaction = null) => {
   // How do I pass transaction as t in this context?
   // Possible?
   return db.runTransaction( t => {
      return t.get(logRef)
         .then(log => {
            if (!log.exists) {
               // blah blah blah
            } else {
               // blah blah blah
            }
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waited for more than a week for an answer, apparently there is no way that we can conditionally `await firestore.runTransaction()` as follow:

```
const updateLog = async (logData, transaction = null) => {
   if (!transaction) {
      transaction = await firestore.runTransaction();
   };
   // Start manipulating data here.
}
```

You just can't **wait for the transaction to complete** and carry out the data manipulation tasks **OUTSIDE** the `runTransaction` -- this is **totally defeating the purpose of transaction**.

#### SOLUTION: Predict for the Unpredictable

The best way to provide the flexibility to be both the standalone and part of the transaction is **NOT to `runTransaction`** in any **direct data manipulative functions** but the outermost caller, e.g. Firebase Functions:

#### data-layer.js

```
   const updateLog = (logData, transaction) => {
      if (!transaction || transaction instanceof admin.firestore.Transaction === false) {
         throw new Error(`Invalid argument: transaction. It must be an instance of Firestore Transaction.`);
      };
      // Assuming logRef has been created here. 
      return transaction.get(logRef)
         .then(log => {
            if (!log.exists) {
               // blah blah blah
            } else {
               // blah blah blah
            }
         }
   }

   const createDoc = (docData, transaction) => {
      if (!transaction || transaction instanceof admin.firestore.Transaction === false) {
         throw new Error(`Invalid argument: transaction. It must be an instance of Firestore Transaction.`);
      };
      // Assuming docRef has been created here. 
      transaction.set(docRef, docData);
      // Here, the updateLog() can be part of the transaction.
      return updateLog(docData, transaction)
         .then(result => {
            if (!result) {
               // blah blah blah
            } else {
               // blah blah blah
            }
         }
   }
```

#### Firebase Function

```
"use strict";
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.createDoc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   const firestore = admin.firestore();
   // Transaction will only be initiated as needed
   // by the caller.
   return firestore.runTransaction(transaction => {
      return createDoc(data.docData, transaction)
         .then(result => {
            // Log has also been updated when running createDoc()
            return result;
          }
   }.catch(error => {
       throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", `${error.message}`);
   };
});

exports.updateLog = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   const firestore = admin.firestore();
   // The updateLog() now can also be standalone.
   return firestore.runTransaction(transaction => {
      return updateLog(data.logData, transaction)
         .then(result => {
            // Log has been updated.
            return result;
          }
   }.catch(error => {
       throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", `${error.message}`);
   };
});
```

#### Conclusion:

It can be a good practice to have each and every smaller data service function to accept the `transaction` parameter and initiate the `runTransaction` only **when they're packed as one complete task**. This should be relatively safe especially when the required `transaction` parameter is validated first and foremost while capable of offering greater flexibility when consuming data services.